# React Native set an alarm that can trigger some code

Tags: android, react-native, alarm

I am developing an application in React Native that can play music using a radio station's stream for this I am using the package https://react-native-track-player.js.org/ which is working fine so far. Now, I need to implement the following, I need to be able to set an alarm that when the time comes does not trigger an actual system alarm, but instead it should start the track player. For example, if I set an alarm at around 8:00 a.m., the application even if it was closed should start again, also it should start playing the music. So far I have not been able to find anything closely related to my problem, could I achieve what I need by writing a native module and if yes how should I start?
Any replies are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm pretty late to the party, but a possible solution could be using [Notifee](https://notifee.app/). Notifee allows triggering a notification at a said date & time and you could handle notification in React Native itself. In this particular scenario, set a notification to be triggered at 8:00AM and when the trigger is received, open an intent to your application(which can start the player).